# How to declare a multi line string on pine script

Tags: string, pine-script, textarea, pine-script-v5

I need to provide a default value for an `input.textarea()` which is a long multi line string containing code.

I'm aware that I can use this approach to break lines

```
text = "line 1\nline2\n..."
```

And even combine it with this to do line wrapping for better readability

```
text = 'line 1\
       line2...'
```

Using the `\` character.

But it'd be much better if there was a "start and end multi line escape codes".

For example if that was `'''` then it would only be a matter of doing:

```
text = '''line 1
       line 2
       line 3'''
```

Many languages offer this and it makes it much easier when the text requires to be copy pasted from/to the code for further editing externally.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function, unfortunately. In the code you have to explicitly declare a new line with escape+n - `\n`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
mystring = "line1 
           \nline2 
           \nline3"
i = input.text_area(mystring, "")
plot(close, display = display.none)
```

[image]
However, if you manually type the multi-line string in the input field, script will recognize any new line automatically.

Multiple lines will still be combined into one line if you don't put \n. In case you put a breaker and then use a space before the character, it will be included in the result:

```
mystring = "line1\n
         line2\n
         line3"
```

[image]

You can also use a oneliner which will result in a multi-line string because of the breakers.

```
mystring = "line1\nline2\nline3"
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I noticed you are breaking the line when declaring the mystring variable. Would that compile? I thought you must also use \ to break the line for example after writing line1

Comment: To put a break for a new line, you must use ```\n```, not just ```\```. Updated my answer with more examples.

Comment: by the way the '\' without the 'n' is also useful! it allows to break your string in multiple lines without becoming multiple lines in the actual output. So it's only for splitting the line in the definition which is also great to know!